# Python OO -- member function definition and keyword self

Tags: python, oop, class, self, member-functions

I am writting a Python class with this constructor:

```
      #constuctor
def __init__(self, initPt_=[1,1],fun_=Optim_tests.peaks,NITER_=30,alpha_=0.7,NMAX_=5000,FTOL_=10**(-10)):
    self.initPt = initPt_
    self.fun = fun_
    self.alpha = alpha_
    self.ITER = NITER_
    self.NMAX = NMAX_
    self.FTOL = FTOL_
```

and defining both member functions:

```
def buildSimplex(self):
    self.simplex=[]
    self.simplex.append([x for x in self.initPt])
    for i in range(len(self.initPt)):
        temp=[x for x in self.initPt]
        temp[i]=self.initPt[i]+1
        self.simplex.append(temp)
    self.npts=len(self.simplex)

def sA(self):
    self.buildSimplex()
```

When calling second functions, error happens:

```
NameError: global name 'buildSimplex' is not defined
```

Do you have a clue?

Comment: Could you provide exact code?

Comment: Added missing member variable so as to remain cohesive. Code details would bring useless code complication.

Comment: @dlib That's not true. It looks like a scoping issue (python is checking the global namespace for your function) so posting the entire class source would be proper.

Comment: Please provide the exact .py file what you wrote in it. Because without that we cant give answer.

Comment: I don't believe this question can be answered in its current state.

Comment: _"Code details would bring useless code complication."_ Trim away all the useless details and post a minimal but complete class that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first sight I would say it's a identation problem, but you need to provide the actual code for a more specific answer.

The reason I'm saying this is because of the error you're getting. If you declared your class properly, and try to call a method of an instance that is not define, you should actually get a: `AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'xxxx'`. And you don't need to care about the order you define your methods if they are declared in a class. See the e xample of `met1` and `met4` below

For example:

```
class A():
   def met1(self):
      print self.met4()

   def met2(self):
      self.met3()

   def met4():
      print 'x'


 a = A()
 a.met1()
 >>> x
 a.met2()
 >>> AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'met3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error `NameError: global name 'buildTool1' is not defined` says you are trying to access the variable `buildTool1` buts its not define in local or global.

Please check this

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def buildSimplex(self):
        print "CALL"

    def sA(self):
        self.buildSimplex()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = test('test')
    x.sA()
```

Comment: All, I amended the code after your remarks. Do you have some comments on new code?

Comment: Here your exemption is running. Please provide the same code which create the problem. From your code we cant generate the error now.

Comment: Thanks for your comments althought the given problem was not well exposed. I understand at least that self.buildSimplex() call in another method and use of keyword self are correct. I will expand if I further test this class.